# Dictionary internal hashcode

Tags: c#, hashcode, equality

When adding objects in a `Dictionary<object,T>`, how does Dictionary know if an object has been added before?

- If answer is `object.GetHashCode()`, then why it is said that we shouldn't trust `object.GetHashCode()` for our own algorithms while we can still use `Dictionary.Add(obj,t)` and expect an exception if obj was added before?
- Else, can I get its internal (hash?)code?

By object, I refer to primitive arrays only.

Maybe even simpler, can we trust

```
Dictionary<object,T> d=new Dictionary<object,T>();
```

that it will not accept same array twice, or it can have two distinct arrays always?

Even simpler, is object.GetHashCode() trusted to be constant for all life-time of an array?

I don't care about element-wise equality.

I'm asking this because I'm working on a network array passing algorithm using tcp sockets and server side must know if it was sent by its client before. Because I'm creating 1 unique buffer for every unique array received from a client.

Comment: It uses a combination of `object.GetHashCode()` and `object.Equals()`. I don't know where you saw that you shouldn't trust `object.GetHashCode()` in your own algorithms. That claim doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: So, in a dictionary, it doesn't change hashcode. Thank you.